# how to show the only instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

Is there a way to see the class specific methods available to an instance through IRB?

I made an instance of the URI class, and then pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see what methods I can use, however I see about 100 possibilities:

```
  1.9.3p286 :001 > require 'uri'
=> true

1.9.3p286 :002 > uri = URI('http://game.dl.a-steroids.com/TrafficServer/')
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000000eae390 URL:http://game.dl.a-steroids.com/TrafficServer/>

  1.9.3p286 :008 > uri.
  Display all 102 possibilities? (y or n)
```

I want to filter only the specific methods for that instance, such as the ones described here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html or below:

```
  1.9.3p286 :003 > uri.host
=> "game.dl.a-steroids.com"

1.9.3p286 :006 > uri.path
=> "/TrafficServer/"

1.9.3p286 :007 > uri.scheme
=> "http"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URI` is a module. It cannot have an instance and it does not have instance methods. To see the module methods directly defined on `URI`, do:

```
URI.methods(false)
```

> # => [:scheme_list, :split, :parse, :join, :extract, :regexp,
>   :encode_www_form_component, :decode_www_form_component,
>   :encode_www_form, :decode_www_form]

And what `URI(...)` creates is an instance of `URI:HTTP`. To see the instance methods directly defined on `URI::HTTP`, do this:

```
URI::HTTP.instance_methods(false)
```

> # => [:request_uri]

---

If this seems too narrow, you can step up to a superclass. `URI` classes are based on `URI::Generic`,

```
URI::HTTP.superclass
```

> # => URI::Generic

so do the same with it:

```
URI::Generic.instance_methods(false)
```

> #=> [:default_port, :scheme, :host, :port, :registry, :path, :query, :opaque, :fragment, :parser, :component, :set_scheme, :scheme=,
>   :userinfo=, :user=, :password=, :set_userinfo, :set_user,
>   :set_password, :userinfo, :user, :password, :set_host, :host=,
>   :hostname, :hostname=, :set_port, :port=, :set_registry, :registry=,
>   :set_path, :path=, :set_query, :query=, :set_opaque, :opaque=,
>   :set_fragment, :fragment=, :hierarchical?, :absolute?, :absolute,
>   :relative?, :merge!, :merge, :+, :route_from, :-, :route_to,
>   :normalize, :normalize!, :to_s, :==, :hash, :eql?, :component_ary,
>   :select, :inspect, :coerce]

Answer (score 1):

I use this in IRB often:

```
uri.methods - Object.methods

=> [
      :+, :-, :absolute, :absolute?, :coerce, :component, :component_ary,
      :default_port, :fragment, :fragment=, :hierarchical?, :host,
      :host=, :hostname, :hostname=, :merge, :merge!, :normalize,
      :normalize!, :opaque, :opaque=, :parser, :password, :password=,
      :path, :path=, :port, :port=, :query, :query=, :registry,
      :registry=, :relative?, :request_uri, :route_from, :route_to,
      :scheme, :scheme=, :select, :set_fragment, :set_host,
      :set_opaque, :set_password, :set_path, :set_port, :set_query,
      :set_registry, :set_scheme, :set_user, :set_userinfo, :user,
      :user=, :userinfo, :userinfo=
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like the following to your .irbrc file, then all objects will get a #own_methods class that you can use to get that list.

```
class Object
  def own_methods
    self.class.instance_methods - self.class.superclass.instance_methods
  end
end
```